# UNION is slow but both queries are fast in separate

Tags: mysql

Dunno what else to do about this one. I have one table that has has a start and a stop columns and I want to return the results of it joined both by start and by stop and I want a clear distinction between the two.
Now both queries run fast separatly:

```
SELECT
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(start_dev, '+00:00', GetCarrierTimezone(a0.carrier_id))) AS alertStart,
            NULL AS alertStop,
            c0.name AS carrier_name,
            carrier_image,
            l0.Latitude,
            l0.Longitude
        FROM
            carriers AS c0
                INNER JOIN start_stop AS a0 ON a0.carrier_id = c0.id
                    INNER JOIN pcoarg AS l0 ON a0.startLogId = l0.id
        WHERE
                FIND_IN_SET(a0.carrier_id, '89467,1,64578,222625,45013') > 0
            AND
                start_dev > '2013-03-11 11:46:48'
            AND 
                start_dev = (SELECT MIN(start_dev) FROM start_stop AS a1 WHERE a0.carrier_id = a1.carrier_id AND DATE(a1.start_dev) = DATE(a0.start_dev))
        AND IsNotificationInSchedule(22, start_dev) > 0
```

So this one takes 0.063.
But if I combine it in a UNION (doesn't matter if it's UNION ALL OR DISTINCT OR WHATEVER) it just takes about 0.400 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    (
        SELECT
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(start_dev, '+00:00', GetCarrierTimezone(a0.carrier_id))) AS alertStart,
            NULL AS alertStop,
            c0.name AS carrier_name,
            carrier_image,
            l0.Latitude,
            l0.Longitude
        FROM
            carriers AS c0
                INNER JOIN start_stop AS a0 ON a0.carrier_id = c0.id
                    INNER JOIN pcoarg AS l0 ON a0.startLogId = l0.id
        WHERE
                FIND_IN_SET(a0.carrier_id, '89467,1,64578,222625,45013') > 0
            AND
                start_dev > '2013-03-11 11:46:48'
            AND 
                start_dev = (SELECT MIN(start_dev) FROM start_stop AS a1 WHERE a0.carrier_id = a1.carrier_id AND DATE(a1.start_dev) = DATE(a0.start_dev))
            AND IsNotificationInSchedule(22, start_dev) > 0
    ) UNION ALL (
        SELECT
            NULL AS alertStart,
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(stop_dev, '+00:00', GetCarrierTimezone(a0.carrier_id))) AS alertStop,
            c0.name AS carrier_name,
            carrier_image,
            l0.Latitude,
            l0.Longitude
        FROM
            start_stop AS a0
                INNER JOIN carriers AS c0 ON a0.carrier_id = c0.id
                    INNER JOIN pcoarg AS l0 ON a0.stopLogId = l0.id
        WHERE
                FIND_IN_SET(a0.carrier_id, '89467,1,64578,222625,45013') > 0
            AND
                stop_dev > '2013-03-11 11:46:48'
            AND 
                stop_dev = (SELECT MAX(stop_dev) FROM start_stop AS a1 WHERE a0.carrier_id = a1.carrier_id AND DATE(a1.stop_dev) = DATE(a0.stop_dev))
            AND IsNotificationInSchedule(22, start_dev) > 0
    )
) AS startStops
ORDER BY IF(alertStart IS NULL, alertStop, alertStart)
```

Here is EXPLAIN on single query:

```
1   PRIMARY c0  ALL PRIMARY             17  Using where
1   PRIMARY a0  ref PRIMARY,startstop_carriers_stopdev_idx,georefidx,startstop_carriers_startdev_idx    startstop_carriers_stopdev_idx  4   test_backoffice.c0.id   72  Using where
1   PRIMARY l0  ref id ASC  id ASC  4   test_backoffice.a0.startLogId   1   Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  a1  ref PRIMARY,startstop_carriers_stopdev_idx,georefidx,startstop_carriers_startdev_idx    startstop_carriers_stopdev_idx  4   test_backoffice.a0.carrier_id   72  Using where; Using index
```

And here is the EXPLAIN for the JOIN:

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  system                  0   const row not found
2   DERIVED c0  ALL PRIMARY             17  Using where
2   DERIVED a0  ref PRIMARY,startstop_carriers_stopdev_idx,georefidx,startstop_carriers_startdev_idx    startstop_carriers_stopdev_idx  4   test_backoffice.c0.id   72  Using where
2   DERIVED l0  ref id ASC  id ASC  4   test_backoffice.a0.startLogId   1   Using where
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  a1  ref PRIMARY,startstop_carriers_stopdev_idx,georefidx,startstop_carriers_startdev_idx    startstop_carriers_stopdev_idx  4   test_backoffice.a0.carrier_id   72  Using where; Using index
4   UNION   c0  ALL PRIMARY             17  Using where
4   UNION   a0  ref PRIMARY,startstop_carriers_stopdev_idx,georefidx,startstop_carriers_startdev_idx    startstop_carriers_stopdev_idx  4   test_backoffice.c0.id   72  Using where
4   UNION   l0  ref id ASC  id ASC  4   test_backoffice.a0.stopLogId    1   Using where
5   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  a1  ref PRIMARY,startstop_carriers_stopdev_idx,georefidx,startstop_carriers_startdev_idx    startstop_carriers_stopdev_idx  4   test_backoffice.a0.carrier_id   72  Using where; Using index
    UNION RESULT    <union2,4>  ALL
```

Help on this one would be greatly appreciated. :)

**EDIT:**

I'm getting inconsistent result. If I remove the convert_tz for example and try to get the timezone outside the union I get very fast results, but If I rename the result it automatically goes down to the same underperformante query:

```
SELECT
    *,
    GetCarrierTimezone(carrier_id) timezone
FROM
(
```

this takes 0.374s

```
SELECT
    *,
    GetCarrierTimezone(carrier_id)
FROM
(
```

while this takes 0.078 (mostly the lag from the db to my machine)..

Comment: The simplest would be to run them separately and combine the results in the application.

Comment: hi @ypercube, that crossed my mind :) but its so ugly to do that and maintain that code. Besides I's still have to sort the results in php.

Comment: I meant run the 2 queries with the wanted sort. Then you only need to merge in php (no sorting).

Comment: The sorting is not linear. The result of query 1 can be in between the results of query 2.

Comment: I don't think @ypercube is assuming the results don't overlap: a 'merge' is much cheaper/easier than a sort to implement in php. Of course fixing the problem in the SQL if possible would be a far better solution :)

Comment: @helderjsm Can you tell us in how much time do the queries need, if you run them separately, adding `ORDER BY alertStart` in the first and `ORDER BY alertStop` in the second?

Comment: @ypercube both run in less than 0.070 seconds which is mostly the time between my machine and the rds.

Comment: Does using `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE` instead of `SELECT` at the beginning of either the faster or slower queries change their performance?  Also, how is GetCarrierTimezone() declared (e.g., `DETERMINISTIC`, `READS SQL DATA`, etc.) and is it referring to local tables?

Comment: As hiyall hinted above, if you don't need to check for duplicates - union all will be much more faster.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect this to happen because of the ORDER BY you have in there.

Try this in the first part of the UNION:

```
SELECT
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(start_dev, '+00:00', GetCarrierTimezone(a0.carrier_id))) AS alertFoo,
            /* NULL AS alertStop, */
```

And this in the second part:

```
SELECT
            /* NULL AS alertStart, */
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(stop_dev, '+00:00', GetCarrierTimezone(a0.carrier_id))) AS alertFoo,
```

And then replace the `ORDER BY` with

```
ORDER BY alertFoo
```

In other words, remove the need for the IF in the order by.

Comment: Hi Thomas, First of all thank you for your replay. Like I said in a previous post this was fixed sometime ago. The thing is I needed the distinction between the alert 1 and alert 2. In any case the order is done on the result of the joins and not on the join itself. There weren't all that many results to justify the slowness of the query.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for the union sql running slower is that a union causes mysqld to create an internal temporary table. It creates just a table for a UNION ALL and a table with an index (to remove duplicates) for a UNION DISTINCT.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In a very very similar case, i noticed from process list of mysql the very bad behaviour of 'copy to temp table' (copying What? I don't know).
I think mysql tempted a 'best approach' for querying, but in this case failed, so using code to 'merge' 2-query results worked fine.

Comment: Hi realtebo, Thanks for the input. This is a bit old now, but for what I remember the inconsistency was because some how mysql was caching some results and not others. I eventually recreated the query in a more efficient way specially by keeping track of the values I needed in a separate table making the indices more efficient.